# Centering a system of differential equation

Tags: latex, system, equation, differential-equations

I am trying write this system of differential equation, all equation it is a left direction, but I would like to ask how to centering the system in the page.

Thank you very much,

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{llll}
\label{eq:siroriginal}
\frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} t} = \delta -\gamma s-\beta si-sk \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} i}{\mathrm{d} t} = -\gamma i+\beta si-\mu i-ik\\
\frac{\mathrm{d} r}{\mathrm{d} t} = \mu i-rk \\
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Have you tried encompassing the equation with `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`?

Comment: Hi HS nebula, Thank you for help me, but doesn't working, I tried, I am very grateful!

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: \usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,indentfirst,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,newlfont,tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{systeme}

Comment: Not sure. Even with all that, I'm able to center the equation.

Comment: Please make a [mre] and not just such a code fragment

Comment: Your documentclass might be issuing left aligned equations, but if you don't make a [mre] that tells us which documentclass you use, it is really impossible to help you

Comment: @HS-nebula Wrapping an equation in a `center` environment is not a good idea, this will mess up the vertical spacing

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh really? Thanks, that's good to know. How does it mess up the vertical spacing?

Comment: @HS-nebula `center` adds additional vertical spacing on top of spacing that equation already inserts. In addition equations alone are quite clever and adjust the spacing based on the how full the line is, I assume that this would also break with `center`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried

```latex
\begin{equation}\label{eq:siroriginal}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} t} &= \delta -\gamma s-\beta si-sk \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} i}{\mathrm{d} t} &= -\gamma i+\beta si-\mu i-ik\\
\frac{\mathrm{d} r}{\mathrm{d} t} &= \mu i-rk \\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
```

using an appropriate amsmath environment and setting the tabulation markers?

If the problem still persists, try posing the question with a full minimal compilable document in tex.SE